# Square root of a complex matrix and eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm stuck on how to start an approach to this question;

Suppose A is an n x n complex matrix with k > 0 distinct eigenvalues, and dim(Null(A)) + k = n, then A = C^2, where C is another complex matrix.

Can you please give hint on how to approach this question?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to say that there are $k$ positive eigenvalues, or are you trying to say that $k>0$ and that there are $k$ eigenvalues?

Comment: There is at least one eigenvalue.

Comment: That's a strange thing to say since *every* matrix has a at least one eigenvalue

Comment: Oh sorry it should be k>0 distinct eigenvalues

Comment: This statement is incorrect as stated.  For instance, with $n=3$ and $k=2$, we find that
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0}
$$
does not have a square root. In this case $A$ has eigenvalues $0,1$.

Comment: To make this clear, taking the square root of A is not possible you are saying?

Comment: Yes that is what I am saying

Comment: Well, the claim is incorrect, so either the question is asking for something impossible or you have misunderstood the question

Comment: Please reread the question and make sure that you have understood it correctly

Comment: Can you please explain how you know that you cannot take the square root of A?

Comment: Did you check your question to make sure that you understood it correctly?

Comment: Yes, my question is exactly as how it is worded.

Comment: All right, I'll write up an answer explaining this then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement is incorrect as stated. For instance, with $n=3$ and $k=2$, we find that 
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0}
$$
does not have a square root.

In this case $A$ has $k=2$ eigenvalues $0,1$ and a $1$ dimensional nullspace, so we indeed have $k + \dim \ker A = n = 3$.

To see that $A$ has no square root: suppose for the purpose of contradiction that $C^2 = A$. It follows that $C$ must have $0$ as an eigenvalue and it must have an eigenvalue from the set $\{-1,1\}$.  Now, $C$ cannot be invertible because it has $0$ as an eigenvalue, so $\operatorname{rank}(C) < 3$. On the other hand, we have $2 = \operatorname{rank}(C^2) \leq \operatorname{rank}(C)$.  So, $\operatorname{rank}(C) = 2$.  Finally, because $C^2$ is not diagonalizable, $C$ cannot be diagonalizable.

It follows that the Jordan form of $C$ must be one the following possibilities:
$$
J_1 = \pmatrix{\pm 1 &1&0\\0&\pm 1&0\\0&0&0 }, \quad J_2 = \pmatrix{\pm 1 &0 &0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0}.
$$
If $C$ is similar to $J_1$, we find that $\operatorname{rank}(C^4) = 2$, which is impossible since $\operatorname{rank}(A^2) = 1$.  If $C$ is similar to $J_2$, we find that $\operatorname{rank}(C^2) = 1$, which is impossible since $\operatorname{rank}(A) = 2$.

So, neither possibility works, which means that we have arrived at a contradiction.  $A$ has no square root.